# Why is my mocha/chai Error throwing test failing?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, throw, referenceerror, chai

I have a simple javascript package I'm trying to test. I want to check for an Error being thrown, but when my test is run, and the error is thrown, the test is marked as failing.

Here's the code:

```
var should = require('chai').should(),
    expect = require('chai').expect();

describe('#myTestSuite', function () {

    it ('should check for TypeErrors', function () {

        // Pulled straight from the 'throw' section of
        // http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/
        var err = new ReferenceError('This is a bad function.');
        var fn = function () { throw err; }
        expect(fn).to.throw(ReferenceError);

    })

})
```

Which, when run gives me the following output:

```
kh:testthing khrob$ npm test

> testthing@0.1.0 test /Users/khrob/testthing
> mocha



  #myTestSuite
    1) should check for TypeErrors


  0 passing (5ms)   1 failing

  1) #myTestSuite should check for TypeErrors:
     TypeError: object is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/khrob/testthing/test/index.js:10:3)
      at callFn (/Users/khrob/testthing/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:249:21)
      at Test.Runnable.run (/Users/khrob/testthing/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:242:7)
      at Runner.runTest (/Users/khrob/testthing/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:373:10)
      at /Users/khrob/testthing/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:451:12
      at next (/Users/khrob/testthing/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:298:14)
      at /Users/khrob/testthing/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:308:7
      at next (/Users/khrob/testthing/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:246:23)
      at Object._onImmediate (/Users/khrob/testthing/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:275:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:336:15)



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details. 
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I know there's dozens of answers on here about what you pass to expect() being a function not the result of a function, and I've tried every permutation of anonymous functionizing I can think of, but I always get the failed test result.

I'm thinking it must be something to do with my config, given that I'm basically just running the example from the documentation, or my expectation for what is a pass or fail on the test is not calibrated properly.

Any clues?

Comment: If you look at the call stack, your test seems to be failing because of an error at line 10: `var err = new ReferenceError('This is a bad function.');` Seems like your runtime environment doesn't recognize `ReferenceError`. What browser/environment are you using to run this test?

Comment: @AtesGoral: It doesn't matter what environment he's running in. You've found the bug: ReferenceError is undefined. Make it an answer. It's up to the OP to figure out why it's not defined.

Comment: Should be a vanilla node environment, but I'll dig into the lack of ReferenceError. Thanks for the insight

Comment: For the breadcrumb trail, `console.log(err, typeof err, ReferenceError);` on line 11 results in: `[ReferenceError: This is a bad function.] 'object' [Function: ReferenceError]`. Investigations continue...

Comment: It is possible that the environment doesn't allow you to programmatically instantiate a ReferenceError because it's an intrinsic exception type.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should fix your problem:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
```

Notice that the `expect` function is not being invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Tracked it down!

Up the top

```
expect = require('chai').expect(),
```

wasn't giving me anything useful. Changing it to:

```
chai = require('chai'),
```

then calling the test as

```
chai.expect(fn).to.throw(ReferenceError);
```

does exactly what I expected.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The accepted answer obviously fixes your issue: your braces after 
expect = require('chai').expect were the issue.