# How to test a Javascript object property when function with mocha, chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, javascript-objects, chai, node-modules

Trying to test a Javascript object

Game.js

```
var GameManager= {
    gameType: 'room',
    roomDimension: [10,10],
    playerDirection: ["W"]
    possibleDirections: ["N","E","S","W"],
    init: function(){
        if(this.gameType == 'room'){
            regexpNumber = /^-?[0-9]$|-?([1][0-9])$/;
        }
    return true;
    },
    turnRight : function(){
    var movePosition = this.possibleDirections.indexOf(this.playerDirection);
    if(movePosition == this.possibleDirections.length -1 ){
        return this.possibleDirections[0];
    }
    return this.possibleDirections[movePosition + 1];
  },
    commandString: function(string){
    var command = /^[PQR]*$/;

    if(command.test(string){
        return true;
    }
    this.errorMessageNumber = 0;
    return false;
}
}
```

Here is my test script **test.js**

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var GameManager = require("../GameManager.js");

describe("Test game type", function() {
   beforeEach(function () {
      GameManager.gameType = 'room';
      GameManager.roomDimension= [10, 10];
      GameManager.possibleDirections: ["N","E","S","W"];
  });

  it('should commandString be as parameters', function() {
    expect(GameManager.commandString("AABB")).to.not.be.false;
  });

  it('should init toBeTruthy', function() {
    expect(GameManager.init()).ok;
  });
});
```

**Issue:** In both cases the test fail with `TypeError` error is shown as below for one of the test:

```
  1) Test game type should init toBeTruthy:
  TypeError: GameManager.init is not a function at Context.<anonymous>
```

Since `init` is not considered as function here, how can this be tested?

Comment: The expectation in the test looks ok , maybe `const expect = require('chai').expect;` the way you are importing chai.

Comment: Also how did you export GameManager ?

Comment: @Hosar Changed the code to `var expect = require("chai").expect;`
And I am not exporting GameManager since it is a simple Javascript object. Not using as `Typescript` export class.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to test a simple object?
I think, although it can be done, the UT are more intended to be behavioral tests.

That said, I think you're using the assert wrong:

```
it('should init toBeTruthy', function() {
   expect(GameManager.init()).to.be.ok;
});
```

Or to be more precise with the test:

```
it('should init toBeTruthy', function() {
   expect(GameManager.init()).to.be.true;
});
```

Also, you may refer to this post, it might be helpful

[Why is my mocha/chai Error throwing test failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072381/why-is-my-mocha-chai-error-throwing-test-failing)

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment:

> I am not exporting `GameManager` since it is a simple Javascript object. Not using as Typescript export class.

You still need to export it. Whether it is a simple JavaScript object or not is utterly irrelevant. You have to write your code in a way that works with Node.js' module system.

Using the code you show in the question, and fixing the syntax errors in it, I can get your second test (the one for `init`) to work if I add this to your `GameManager.js` file:

```
module.exports = GameManager;
```

With the code you show in the question, the exported value from `GameManager.js` is `{}`. So when you do `var GameManager = require("../GameManager.js");` the `GameManager` variable gets assigned the value `{}`. Consequently `GameManager.init` has the value `undefined`, and thus it is not a function. Adding the line I show above, will make it so that the `GameManager` variable in your test file gets the value of `GameManager` from your `GameManager.js` file, and the test will pass.

(You did not provide code for `GameManager.commandString` so the first test will still fail. Just add the code for it to get it to work.)

Comment: Added suggested line on the `GameManager.js` keeping `var GameManager = require("../GameManager.js");`, but test would always fail at ` GameManager.gameType = 'room';` as shown `undefined` and `TypeError: Cannot set property 'gameType' of undefined:` is shown. All the changes didn't make it work for some reason.